# how to get the server time in the Firestore in the map from the class

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

Adding to Firestore from a class instance

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection').add({'history':History(FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), 'action', 'who').makeMap()}).then((value) {
  // ...
});
```

what type should the time field have?

```
class History{

    FieldValue time  = FieldValue.serverTimestamp();
    String action = '';
    String who = '';
    var history =  <FieldValue, Map<String, String>>{};

    History(FieldValue time, String action, String who){
       this.time = time;
       this.action = action;
       this.who = who;
    }

    Map<FieldValue, Map<String, String>> makeMap(){
        var tempMap = <String, String>{
            'action' : action,
            'who' : who,
        };
        history[time] = tempMap;
        return history;
   }

}
```

How to get a string in this form?

```
{"time" : 'October 25, 2022 at 10:44:39 PM UTC+1' ,
{ "action": "action", "who": "who" }};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to store the value of time in `timeStamp` type and when to get also save in `timeStamp` then easily you can convert into string